# Exchange data between iOS apps

Tags: ios

I know about x-callback-url, and how it's possible to e.g. send a string to an app in iOS.

But is it possible to do this the other way around, e.g is it possible for an iOS app to fetch the song currently playing in Music.app? Can an app fetch a message with a specific caller ID from Messages.app?

Comment: so basically you want to hijack other apps data?

Comment: No, I'm not a crook ;) I want my app to read the content of an SMS that my gateway has sent, for device authorization.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you need to have access to their API/backend to do that. Talking directly to another iOS app is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

> No, I'm not a crook ;) I want my app to read the content of an SMS that my gateway has sent, for device authorization.

register a scheme for your app. add a link with that scheme in your sms, with the registration code as uri-path. by clicking that should open your app and you can process the uri.

Comment: That's a really good idea. We were playing around with something similar.